# Appending list with highest value from two columns using for loop in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop

I have two columns: column A, and column B.

I would like to find whether the value in each row of column A is larger than the value for the same row in column B, and if it is append a list with these values.

I'm able to append the list if the value in column A is higher than a set value, but I'm unsure how to compare it to the value from column B.

The below code appends the list if the value in column A is higher than 4. Hopefully I'm on the right track and can just substitute 4 with some other code?

```
list = []

for x in A:
    if x > 4:
        list.append(x)

print(list)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach could be:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[2, 3, 4, 5], "B":[1, 4, 6, 3]}) # Test DataFrame

print(list(df[df["A"] > df["B"]]["A"]))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[2, 5]
```

**FOLLOW UP**

If, as described in the comments, you want to check conditions on multiple columns:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[2, 3, 4, 5], "B":[1, 4, 6, 3], "C":[1, 1, 1, 10]}) # Test DataFrame

print(list(df[(df["A"] > df["B"]) & (df["A"] > df["C"])]["A"]))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[2]
```

Comment: Regarding the above answer. How would I edit the code if I wanted to add a further column, C. So that only values from A were given if they were greater than values in column B and C? I can't seem to make it work, but don't really understand the above process (although it does work perfectly!).